# Error: Cannot find module 'connect'

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

It appears that this simple app can't find the `'connect'` module after I just installed it in the file directory.

```
var connect = require ('connect');

connect.createServer(function(res, req, next) {
    res.simpleBody("Connect you son of a beeeeetch");

}).listen(8000);



express@3.1.0 node_modules/express
├── methods@0.0.1
├── fresh@0.1.0
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── cookie-signature@0.0.1
├── buffer-crc32@0.1.1
├── cookie@0.0.5
├── debug@0.7.2
├── commander@0.6.1
├── mkdirp@0.3.3
├── send@0.1.0 (mime@1.2.6)
└── connect@2.7.2 (pause@0.0.1, bytes@0.1.0, formidable@1.0.11, qs@0.5.1)
Dzs-Mac-Attax-2:PlsWrk Dz$ node test.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Dz/Documents/NodeTests/PlsWrk/test.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) internally uses [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) as one of its node_modules dependencies.

If you wish to use Connect in your app, you'll need to add it to your `package.json` and run `npm update`.

By design, each node module has its own private internal dependencies.

If you want to use any, your app will need to install them too.

It means your app can use a different version of the modules, and each module can internally use different versions again without conflicts.

Comment: It worked after I added explcit dependency in package.json and ran npm update when it actually downloaded connect package to the local.
Thanks for the tips

Comment: If you are using Express, which builds on top of Connect, then you should be using Express to start the server. If you are using Connect directly, what are you using Express for? A 2nd server?

Answer (score 8):

**Connect** is an extensible HTTP server framework that Express uses. In particular Express uses it provide support for sessions and cookie handling. The source code is available on github at https://github.com/senchalabs/connect.

Generally when a node application 'can't find' something the first thing to try is to go to https://npmjs.org/package/npm-search and search for what can't be found. It would be hard to get along in the node eco-system without using npm.

In this case npmsearch will find connect and if you go to https://npmjs.org/package/connect you'll find the installation instructions for the connect module.

In this case :

```
npm install connect

npm -g install connect
```

installs the connect module for every user.

You may need to be root or use sudo to do this on most unix distributions.

Alternatively you can add the connect dependency to your project's package.json file - mine looks like this:

```
"express": "3.x" ,
"connect": "2.x"
```

I also had to use npm to install the modules buffer-crc32, methods, debug, fresh, range-parser, cookie-signature and cookie to get a working express project.

Happy node hacking :)

Answer (score 6):

The connect module either is not installed or installed partially so install it firstly and later on try to start the server again

```
  npm install connect
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following command, this might happen if you forget to install the connect serve-static module or installed it incorrectly.

```
$ npm install connect serve-static
```

Answer (score 1):

because you didn't install it. you have `express` installed, not `connect`.

Comment: Isn't the connect@2.7.2 module installed with express as listed above or do I have to install in separately?

Comment: yes. but you can not `require()` it unless you explicitly install it yourself. it's `express`'s dependency, not your own.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Node installed into the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`. Initially I was trying to install and run javascript files from this directory, which caused numerous permissions problems.

If you've put your server in that directory, try moving it to another directory (perhaps in `Documents`), navigate there in your Node command prompt, and try running again.

That worked out-of-the-box for me.

Answer (score 0):

(Win7) I have a Command window open as an administrator
I made a directory under C:\Program Files (x86)\NodeJS
I navigated the Command window via cd C:\Program Files (x86)\NodeJS

I ran commands
    npm install connect

response:
    [redacted]>npm -g install connect
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    npm ERR! argv " [redacted]\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "-g"  "install" "connect"
    npm ERR! node v0.12.7
    npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
    npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
    npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
    npm ERR! syscall connect

```
npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!      [redacted]\npm-debug.log
```

I ran 
    npm config edit
I changed the attribute lines to eliminate the semi-colon at the start of each of those lines.

Again, I ran
    npm -g install connect

same result.  The log file has this:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ ' [redacted]\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   ' [redacted]\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'connect' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.3
3 info using node@v0.12.7
4 verbose install initial load of  [redacted]\package.json
5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from [redacted]\package.json
6 silly cache add args [ 'connect', null ]
7 verbose cache add spec connect
8 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'connect',
8 silly cache add   scope: null,
8 silly cache add   name: 'connect',
8 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
8 silly cache add   spec: '*',
8 silly cache add   type: 'range' }
9 silly addNamed connect@*
10 verbose addNamed "*" is a valid semver range for connect
11 silly addNameRange { name: 'connect', range: '*', hasData: false }
12 silly mapToRegistry name connect
13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
14 silly mapToRegistry registry ht tps://registry.npmjs.org/
15 silly mapToRegistry uri ht tps://registry.npmjs.org/connect
16 verbose addNameRange registry:ht tps://registry.npmjs.org/connect not in flight; fetching
17 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
18 verbose request no auth needed
19 info attempt registry request try #1 at 12:36:52 PM
20 verbose request id 3524fc7ca91c73dc
21 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
22 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
23 info attempt registry request try #2 at 12:37:26 PM
24 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
25 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
26 info attempt registry request try #3 at 12:38:50 PM
27 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
28 verbose stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
28 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
28 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1010:19)
29 verbose cwd [redacted]
30 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
31 error argv "[redacted]\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g"     "install" "connect"
32 error node v0.12.7
33 error npm  v2.11.3
34 error code ETIMEDOUT
35 error errno ETIMEDOUT
36 error syscall connect
37 error network connect ETIMEDOUT
37 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
37 error network and is related to network connectivity.
37 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
37 error network
37 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
37 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
38 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I guess I will just use IIS Express.  This *hundreds of files to do something* simple is just beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for express-http-proxy and the solution was to install the package with npm. At first I installed globally (-g) and it works. On another installation I had to use "--save-dev".

```
$ gulp
module.js:338
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express-http-proxy'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/opt/jet/workspace/node-js-project/lib/authorization-to-context-header.js:1:75)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

**installing the package**

```
$ npm install express-http-proxy -g
express-http-proxy@0.6.0 /opt/jet/nodejs/node-js/lib/node_modules/express-http-proxy
âââ type-is@1.6.6 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.4)
âââ raw-body@1.3.4 (bytes@1.0.0, iconv-lite@0.4.8)
```

or if the "-g" is not enough

```
$ npm install express-http-proxy --save-dev
```

**gulp works**

```
$ gulp
[16:49:17] Using gulpfile /var/opt/workspace/node-js-project/gulpfile.js
[16:49:17] Starting 'dev'...
[16:49:17] Starting 'clean'...
[16:49:17] Finished 'dev' after 9.18 ms
[16:49:17] Starting 'default'...
[16:49:17] Finished 'default' after 10 Î¼s
[16:49:17] Finished 'clean' after 11 ms
[16:49:17] Starting 'build'...
[16:49:17] Starting 'clean'...
[16:49:17] Finished 'clean' after 2.13 ms
[16:49:17] Starting 'styles'...
[16:49:17] Finished 'styles' after 813 ms
...
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem :

```
npm install connect
```

solved it