# resolve the error module.js:339

Tags: node.js

This is my `server.js` code and I want a solution on how to resolve the error: `can't find the module 'connect'`

```
var connect = require('connect');

var port = 3000;

connect.createServer connect.static(__dirname )

).listen(port);

console.log('Connect via port '+port);
```

Comment: do you have the module installed? Running `npm -i connect` should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot find module 'connect'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351995/error-cannot-find-module-connect)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package connect. Use the npm install command to install the connect package.

```
npm install connect
```

Comment: but when i m using npm install connect then also i have a problem  npm warn ENOENT: no such file or directory  c:\nodeapps\package.json  how to resolve it

Comment: Did you execute the command 'npm install' from the c:\nodeapps directory? If not, then open command prompt set the current directory to c:\nodeapps and then execute the command c:\nodeapps. If this still doesn't work, it is possible you have install connect globally, and you need to link it using 'npm link connect'

Comment: Also can you confirm that the server.js file is located in the same directory as your package.son.

Comment: Please try the following commands in a command window. 1. Set the path to c:\nodeapps 2. Execute "npm install connect"

Comment: If this doesn't work, please list the contents of your package.json file and execute the following command by setting the current directory to c:\nodeapps "npm list" and print out the contents of that too.

Comment: sir please suggest me another way how to download and install node module inside c:\nodeapps  directory .